# How to pass an unknown data type through to printf in C

Tags: c

I'm porting some C code which contains function calls like this:

```
...
char string[] = "Hello";
int data = 3;
char fmt[] = "%d";
printit(string, &data, fmt);
...
/* Elsewhere */

char string[] = "Hello";
float fdata = 3.1416;
char ffmt[] = "%f";
printit(string, &fdata, ffmt);
```

The function prototype for printit is:

`void printit( char *s, void *data, char *format);`

I don't have the code for printit (that's part of what I have to do in porting), but from context it is supposed to print the first string then pass the data and format to printf. At various points in the code, printit is called with data of various types. Since the number of arguments to printit is always the same, it doesn't seem like the whole machinery of varargs should be necessary to accomplish this but I haven't cracked a simpler way. What am I missing?

Comment: `I'm porting some C code` but that's not valid C. You need to show a [mcve] of the original code and the converted code

Comment: Do you mean: `void printit(char *s, void *data, char *format)`?

Comment: stdarg is very light on most known to me implementations. I bet that "optimized" printf will (or is) be less efficient. BTW try to ask question which make any sense. Posting code which makes no sense does not help

Comment: `void data` is not a valid declaration. Perhaps you meant `void *data`. Show the correct exact text of the `printit` declaration. Also show samples of calls to it, including enough code to see the types of data passed to it.

Comment: I suggest [this entry in the C faq](http://c-faq.com/varargs/vprintf.html). Or use `fputs`? Not quite sure.

Comment: This is going to be kind of tricky.  I think you're going have to do a rudimentary parse of the format string, looking at (at least) the last character, and under some circumstances the last two or three characters.  Then depending on those characters, figure out which type of argument to expect (`d`→`int`, `ld`→`long`, `d`→`double`, etc.), and fetch it, and then call `printf` with it.  How you fetch the argument will depend on whether or not the second argument is (as other commenters have suspected) actually of type `void *`.

Comment: Now that you have fixed the `void *`, what specifically is your question? An implementation of `printit` will typically examine the `format` string. When it finds a character or characters indicating what type of data it needs to operate on, then it will convert the `void *data` parameter to a pointer to the appropriate type and operate on it. This might be done for multiple types via a `switch` statement, or it might be done through a variety of `if` and `else` statements. What specific question do you have about this?

Comment: This `printit` function makes zero sense. Why is it needed? Just call `printf` or whatever directly.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: `printit` could send its output to multiple streams, such as a log file and the standard error stream. It might send output only if some debugging flag is on. You do not know what it does, and that is not an issue in this question; commenting on it is just a distraction.

Comment: You wrote what it does, I quote "is supposed to print the first string then pass the data and format to printf". If it does something else, say so in the question. Anyway, implementing `printit` with the specified API involves parsing the format string like (some subset if) `printf` does. Implementing a different version of `printit` that has a more printf-like interface allows you to avoid parsing and delegate it to whatever printf-family functions are called inside. Choose wisely.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: I did not write that. OP wrote it and is surmising “from context.”

Comment: @Eric Sorry I have no idea who writes what, so here's a correctiin.  OP wrote what printit is supposed to do in the body of the queation. If you think something different is needed, perhaps a different question body is needed.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: I have already asked OP to clarify the question and voted to close.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a skeleton of the code I think you're going to need:

```
void printit(char *s, void *data, char *format)
{
    char fmt[4];
    fmt[0] = format[strlen(format)-1];    /* last char of format */
    fmt[1] = '\0';

    fputs(s, stdout);

    if(strcmp(fmt, "d") == 0) {
        int i = *(int *)data;
        printf(format, i);
    } else if(strcmp(fmt, "f") == 0) {
        double d = *(double *)data;
        printf(format, d);
    } ...
}
```

The key to this is that, once we know what type we're operating on, we take the "generic" `data` pointer and cast it to a "real" pointer type (`int *`, `double *`, etc.), and indirect on it with `*` to fetch the pointed-to value.

You'll have to do a trickier extraction of `fmt` if you want to handle types `long int` (`%ld`), `long double` (`%Lf`), or `long long int` (`%lld`).